# Facebook graph API: Event timezone, time

Tags: ios, facebook, events, facebook-graph-api

I am currently having a problem with getting the correct time for an event via Facebook's graph API. There are some events showing the correct time and some are not. Even if I am calculating the timezone wrongly, it just doesn't make sense to me.

For example I have the following three events: "Brunch", "Champions league finale" and "Pfingst-Tanz". That's what the graph API gives back:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Pfingst-Tanz",
         "start_time": "2012-05-27T10:00:00",
         "end_time": "2012-05-27T14:00:00",
         "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
         "location": "...",
         "id": "..."
      },
      {
         "name": "Championsleague Finale",
         "start_time": "2012-05-19T11:45:00",
         "end_time": "2012-05-19T14:45:00",
         "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
         "location": "...",
         "id": "..."
      },
      {
         "name": "Muttertagsbrunch",
         "start_time": "2012-05-13T10:00:00",
         "end_time": "2012-05-13T14:00:00",
         "location": "...",
         "id": "..."
      }
   ],
   "paging": { … }
}
```

On the Facebook page it shows:

- Pfingst-Tanz 19:00 (07:00 pm)
- Champions league finale 20:45 (8:45 pm)
- Brunch 10:00 (10:00 am)

Which results in:

- Pfingst-Tanz: Facebook page correct, API incorrect or TZ incorrect in my app
- (Champions league finale: don't know, never mind)
- Brunch: Facebook page and API correct and same

This just does not correspond to each other. From what I understand it has to be either all wrong or none wrong, but not just 1/3 or 2/3 events. Does anyone have an idea, or am I just too blind to see something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "Brunch" event doesn't include a time zone, so it can't be adjusted to the user's local time zone, which is what I assume Facebook is doing.

It's not immediately clear to me whether the `start_time` and `end_time` values are meant to represent the *local* start/end times (in the given time zone) or the UTC start/end times, but that should be easy enough to work out based on the data (and documentation, hopefully). I suspect it's the UTC start/end when there's a time zone specified, but the *local* start/end otherwise.

Comment: Ah, see, I didn't notice that. Thanks a lot! Seems like it's only correct if I leave away the TZ in both the app and the fb page right now, because I don't take it into account in my app at all.

Comment: Just to make sure everything's said about this issue: If a timezone is given when creating the event on Facebook, the Graph API will recalculate the date/time to reflect Pacific Standard Time (PST). Not a very elegant solution at FB's side, but I think they will have to stick to that now. A developer using the Graph API will then have to load the event with PST in mind and then recalculate by adding the difference from PST to his own timezone. But, keep in mind that it is only like this when a tz is set. When no tz is set, there will be no recalculation for the Graph API.

Comment: @arnekolja: Really - it uses PST for everything? Aargh! (I assume it actually uses Pactific Time, either standard or daylight depending on the time of year?)

Comment: Yes, I rubbed my eyes, too. See the description for start_time here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/ - edit: PT, didn't know there is daylight saving for Pacific Time, sorry :-)

Comment: @arnekolja: Wow. That's a really broken bit of API design. Well done for tracking it down! (I'm interested that specifying a time zone is "not recommended" - some events are naturally in a time zone, and some aren't. There shouldn't be a recommendation one way or another...)

Comment: This is especially interesting, because the timezone seems to bet set automatically if you choose a specific location for your event. I am not familiar with FB pages, but my "temporary bug fix", removing the timezone from these events, didn't work out, as I cannot remove the tz without removing the location. This is failure by design :-) Looks like they're trying to fix it in the frontend, but it breaks at the other end.